# bash: test if a process is running with a certain option

Tags: bash, process

I would to know if it's possible to detect if amarok is playing music or not, in bash.

I have tested

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$(pidof amarok --play)" ] 
then
  echo amarok is playing music!
else
  echo amarok is not playing!
fi
```

But I have this error:

```
pidof: invalid options on command line!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pidof` thinks that `--play` is its option, and that is of course an error.

It would be better to check if `--play` is inside the commandline that was used to start `amarok`:

```
grep -- --play /proc/$(pidof amarok)/cmdline
```

Another option is to `grep` output of `ps aux`:

```
ps aux | grep [a]marok.*--play
```

In the both cases we suppose that there only one amarok running in the system.

**Update 1.**

To check if any music is playing at the moment,
you can so:

```
grep RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status
```

Comment: This requires a `/proc` filesystem, but I don't think there is anything better / more portable.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if `--play` is really detected. It says "not playing" even if it plays. I'm launching amarok with graphical icon, and play music later, manually... So maybe the `--play` option is not set!